# (H.W question) In Mathemaical Analysis of Rudin example 1.1 Pg 2

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

The author went on and proved that

1) There exists no rational $p$ such that $p^2=2$

2) He defined two sets $A$ and $B$ such that if $p\in A$ then $p^2 <2$ and if $p\in B$ then $p^2>2$ and then constructed $$q=p - \frac{p^2-2}{p+2}$$ and $$q^2-2=\frac{2(p^2-2)}{(p+2)^2}$$

Then **$A$ contains no largest element and $B$ contains no smallest element**

Finally in the remark he said that the purpose of the above exercise was to show that the rational number system has certain gaps.

So my question is how is 2) used in arriving at this conclusion? I basically didn't understand the purpose of 2) in this discussion.

Comment: There is on root(-1) and there is no "even prime > 2" but these aren't "gaps".  The rational square root of 2 isn't a gap because it doesn't exist.  It's a "gap" because it doesn't exist *AND* you can get infinitiely close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ contained a largest element $p$. Now we have $p^2-2<0$. Then we must have $q^2-2=\frac{2(p^2-2)}{(p+2)^2}<0$ as the numerator on the right hand side is negative and the corresponding denominator positive.

So $q\in A$. However $q=p-(\mbox{negative quantity})$ i.e. $q=p+\mbox{positive quantity}$ by definition. So $q>p$ contradicting the $p$ was the largest element. So $A$ has no largest element. A similar argument works for $B$.

Comment: I understand the proof presented, but I didn't understand its purpose- why was it written and what relevance does it hold in discussion of root 2 in not rational.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh: This does not prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. It shows that there is no last rational number before $\sqrt{2}$ (and none immediately succeeding it). In other words as we "go on increasing" the numbers of $A$ we will never strike an end number before we go out of $A$. This indicates that there is a gap between $A$ and its complement. Such a situation never happens within the reals even though there are equations which do not possess solution in the reals just like rationals do not possess a solution for $x^2-2=0$.

Comment: **In other words as we "go on increasing" the numbers of A we will never strike an end number before we go out of A** - I think this statement implies there are infinite many rationals in A, I still couldn't link it to the existence of gaps. Also would you elaborate your remark with an example from real on the last sentence you wrote.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh: Think in this way: Assume you don't know anything about real numbers. Now do you think the natural numbers have gaps? Our intuition suggests no as it will never happen that for a bounded above set there is a break whilst we are counting them. We will always reach an ending value (the greatest element) and count on smoothly. So natural numbers do not have gaps. On the other hand such smooth counting is not possible in the rationals. So the rational numbers have gaps.

Comment: My reason for making the comment regarding the reals was so that you do not think that the gap occurs because $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. Similarly $\sqrt{-1}$ is also not real but that causes no gaps in the reals.

Answer (score 4):

Rudin doesn't give a #*@$ whether there is a rational square root of 2 or not. What he's trying to show is that you can divide all the rational numbers into two sets that exhaust the rationals; that one set can have every element larger than every element in the other yet it is possible to have no limits to either set; you can take infinitely many larger numbers in one set and never have a largest and you can take infinitely many for the other set and never have a lowest one yet the two sets can be infinitely close together approaching ... something... but that something not being anything that can exist in the rationals.

Thus we can say the rational are incomplete but that these incomplete "gaps" are infinitesimally small.

He shows this by quickly proving $(m/n)^2 = 2$ is impossible.  Ho-hum.  Too bad how sad. Who cares.  But once that has been shown comes the important part.

You can divide the rationals entirely into two sets.  All the $m/n$ where $(m/n)^2 > 2$ and all the $m/n$ where $(m/n)^2 < 2$.  And both sets are infinite and all can get infinitely close to the other set but neither set has a highest (or lowest) element despite clearly there being a "wall" they can't go past, but can never actually hit, either.

The **only** reason he cares that there is no rational square root of 2 is that of these two sets the option $(m/n)^2 = 2$ is simply not available.

That's the point.